# Function with increasing property.

Tags: calculus, functions

Prove that $\frac{1}{2}(x+2)^{-3/2}-(\frac{1}{2}x+3)(x+3)^{-3/2}$ is increasing function for $x\ge4$.

I tried it by taking its first derivative but by first derivative for me its difficult to say it is increasing for $x\ge4$. Following is the first derivative

$(x+3)^{-5/2}(\frac{x}{4}+3)-\frac{3}{4}(x+2)^{-5/2}$

Comment: What did you get for the first derivative?

Comment: Edited @Khallil

Answer (score 1):

Let you function be represented by $f(x)$, then $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{3}{(x+2)^{5/2}}+\frac{1}{(x+3)^{3/2}}+\frac{9}{(x+3)^{5/2}}\right)$$

now define $$g(x)=(x+2)^{5/2} (x+3)^{5/2}f'(x)$$ simplify a bit to have $$4g(x)=x \Big(x \left(x\sqrt{x+2} +16 \sqrt{x+2}-3 \sqrt{x+3}\right)+52 \sqrt{x+2}-18 \sqrt{x+3}\Big)+48 \sqrt{x+2}-27 \sqrt{x+3}$$

Now show that $48 \sqrt{x+2}-27 \sqrt{x+3}>0$, and $52 \sqrt{x+2}-18 \sqrt{x+3}>0$ and that $x\sqrt{x+2} +16 \sqrt{x+2}-3 \sqrt{x+3}>0$.

For the first 
\begin{align}
48 \sqrt{x+2}-27 \sqrt{x+3}&>0\\
48 \sqrt{x+2}&>27 \sqrt{x+3}\\
48^2 (x+2)&>27^2 (x+3)\\
1575x+2421>0\\
\end{align}

For the second 
\begin{align}
52 \sqrt{x+2}-18 \sqrt{x+3}&>0\\
52 \sqrt{x+2}&>18 \sqrt{x+3}\\
52^2 (x+2)&>18^2 (x+3)\\
2380x+4436>0\\
\end{align}

For the last
\begin{align}
x\sqrt{x+2} +16 \sqrt{x+2}-3 \sqrt{x+3}&>0\\
(x+16) \sqrt{x+2}&>3 \sqrt{x+3}\\
(x+16)^2 (x+2)&>3^2 (x+3)\\
x^3+34 x^2+311 x+485>0\\
\end{align}

Comment: @mathlove thanks for being careful on that :-) I just corrected this.